# How Jenkins git publisher can tag Visual Studio Online git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops

I am using Jenkins to build .net applications hosted in Git repo that resides in Visual studio online.
I am using git publisher plugin.
I want to tag my build on promotions.
Jenkins is running on a windows server in AWS EC2.
Visual studio online git does not support  SSH.

When I try to create a tag I get these errors:

```
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe tag -l Tag-v64 # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe tag -a -f -m Jenkins Git plugin tagging with Tag-v64 Tag-v64 # timeout=10
ERROR: Failed to push tag Tag-v64 to origin
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not apply tag Tag-v64
at    org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.tag(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1210)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:274)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:289)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782    )
    at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe tag -a -f -m Jenkins Git plugin tagging with Tag-v64 Tag-v64" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: 
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

I have already setup alternate credentials in Visual studio online.
I can manually run config commands mentioned above.
I have even downloaded the https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

I can use git to successfully clone my git repo. I was hoping that running the clone prompts me for the password and it will automatically get stored in git credential manager but it is not work.
I did restart jenkins service.

But I keep on getting the same errors.

Let me know if somebody has done this. 
I will love to use git repo other than Visual studio online but I don't have a choice.

Thanks

Comment: When you used Git to clone the repo, where you connected with the jenkins user (the one used by the Jenkins service)?

Comment: Jenkins is running as a user that is a local user account on the VM only. When I used git to clone the repo I used alternate credentials setup in visual studio online.  I used git config --global credential.helper wincred to store my credentials. My credential were stored and now when I clone a repo using command line I don't get prompted for password.  But jenkins git publisher is still giving me the same error as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) for Jenkins Source Code Management in the build task. It allows me to add and save the credentials to connect to a VSO Git Repository. After this, the tag can be added in VSO successfully if I add Git Publisher in Post-build actions.

The credentials I use is generated by following steps:

1. Open the project from VSO Web Portal.
2. Click "Code" to open "Code" panel.
3. Click "Clone" button.
4. Click "Generate Git credentials" button.

Copy and paste the credentials in Git Plugin.

Comment: Eddie,  I followed the steps 1 to 4 to generate git credentials. Previously I was using alternate credentials and Jenkins was able to get source code build it. The only thing that was not working was being able to push a tag. I created a new credential in Jenkins. This time I specified user name as my email address that I am using to log into VSO. I specified the generated credential as my password. This is not working. Now I cannot even connect with VSO successfully. I get this error Failed to connect to repository : status code 128:
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for git rep.

Comment: Can you check the user name of the generated credentials? In my case, the user name generated is the name of my project, not my email address.